# Adobe Acrobat converting data entered into fdf

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, fdf

How can i convert the data entered in Adobe Acrobat form fields (using submit button) to a fdf file? Anybody has any ideas.?

Comment: there were several questions on this topic here. try searching

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML to PDF very simply - i use this

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/